# Why we need callback if I can done synchronised task without callback

Tags: javascript, callback

actually my question sounds like dumb question to you but I have some doubt about callback

```
function a(fn){
 Console.log(1,2,3)
  fn()
}

function b(){
console.log(4,5,6)
}

a(b)
//Output
//1,2,3
//4,5,6
```

But I can do this kind of same thing by following approach

```
function a(){
 Console.log(1,2,3)
  fn()
}

function b(){
console.log(4,5,6)
}
a()
b()
//Output
//1,2,3
//4,5,6
```

I have already mentioned that my question look like dumb to you but what's the difference between this two approaches and what's the benefits or drawback using callback here.
Thankyou

Comment: Callback functions are used primarily in asynchronous tasks. In a sync environment, you can use them to prevent repetitive code.

Comment: One reason I can think of is future-proofing: i.e you expect `a()` to be async in the future, but for now it's just returning a sync result (for example an API mock). This way your code is already async-proof.